# tcltk not loading and causes R-gui to become unresponsive or crash

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit, rgui

I've run into a problem with getting tcltk to run properly on r-gui. It's a required package for one of the packages (aplpack) I'd like to work with.

---

Preliminary Stuff
13" Macbook Air
OSX Yosemite - Version 10.10.5
R Version 3.2.3
R.app GUI 1.66 (6956) x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0

r and r-gui were installed via homebrew

---

I installed aplpack in order to use the bagplot function. Upon loading the package I received the following output:

> Loading required package: tcltk 2015-12-23 09:44:11.134 R[6529:31353]
>   -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800011b3f0 2015-12-23 09:44:11.135 R[6529:31353] ***
>   run_REngineRmainloop: exception -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x60800011b3f0 caught during REPL iteration.
>   Update to the latest GUI version and consider reporting this properly
>   (see FAQ) if it persists and is not known. Consider saving your work
>   soon in case this develops into a problem.

The session became unresponsive and I had to force quit.

To try and solve the problem, I checked to see if tcltk was installed:

> ```
> > capabilities()["tcltk"]
> ```
>
> tcltk
>   TRUE

It was also available via the package manager but trying to load it, both through the gui and using library("tcltk") caused R to become unresponsive and resulted in an identical error:

> 2015-12-23 09:49:24.370 R[6571:33844] -[NSApplication _setup:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000108f70 2015-12-23
>   09:49:24.370 R[6571:33844] *** run_REngineRmainloop: exception
>   -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000108f70 caught during REPL iteration. Update to the latest GUI
>   version and consider reporting this properly (see FAQ) if it persists
>   and is not known. Consider saving your work soon in case this develops
>   into a problem.

Some googling led me to do the following:

- uninstall r-gui via homebrew
- uninstall r via homebrew
- download and install the most recent version of xquartz
- installed homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk (which I thought was supposed to fix the issue)
- ran brew update
- ran brew upgrade
- ran brew doctor
- installed r via homebrew
- installed r-gui via homebrew

After taking the above steps, I'm still running into the same issue as before. 
Here is the output of sessionInfo():

> > sessionInfo() R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.10.5
> >     (Yosemite)
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base

Following the advice in the Mac OSX FAQ (to attempt to replicate the issue), I opened the r in terminal and was able to not only load tcltk, but also aplpack:

> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" Copyright (C)
>   2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> > sessionInfo() R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.10.5
> >     (Yosemite)
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> > library("aplpack") Loading required package: tcltk
> >     sessionInfo() R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.10.5
> >     (Yosemite)
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices
>   utils     datasets  methods   [8] base
>
> other attached packages: [1] aplpack_1.3.0

---

I believe that the issue with loading tcltk is interfering with loading aplpack and that something in R.app/r-gui is not playing nicely with tcltk.

Comment: So… what actually is the question?

Comment: @Donal Fellows, I'm sorry for my lack of clarity. I'm not sure exactly what the errors mean and it would be nice to have an english translation. Also, I was hoping someone would be able to suggest a work around/solution for me to be able to run tcltk in R.app or at the very least suggest a place for me to start (beyond what I've already tried).

Comment: Ah, the error means that everything is messed up. Do you have the exact version of the Tcl and/or Tk library that you're using available? (They're typically a matched pair.) There's been a lot of fixing of the OSX version of Tk relatively recently that hasn't necessarily made it into the system version of Tk yet.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, the version of tcl I'm using is 8.5 (patch level 8.5.9).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding

```
install.packages("tcltk")
```

Returns

> package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)

A work around would be to use the previous version of R which is compatible with tcltk.